# Detecting a service worker eviction

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

When a browser detects that storage is criticaly low, it can choose to evict a service worker's cache, as stated by the [W3C doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#storage-considerations).

Since my users can choose to store their bookings for offline acces, I want to warn them that the browser has deleted them. How can I detect from the page that my Service Worker has lost its cache and thus modifiy the UI accordingly?

Usually, I adapt my UI to the presence or absence of my Service Worker by relying on `navigator.serviceWorker.register`. But in this case, the Service Worker is still registered, but cache-deprived.

Reacting to the `onevicted` event is not enough, since the cache deletion could happen while the user is not even browsing my web site.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to request [Persistent Storage](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/persistent-storage). That article refers to an [Origin Trial](https://github.com/jpchase/OriginTrials/blob/gh-pages/developer-guide.md) that started with Chrome 52, but it's since become enabled by default in Chrome 55+, so there's no longer a need to go through the Origin Trial signup process.

Assuming you're not using Persistent Storage, I am not aware of any event that's triggered on the service worker when your origin's stored data is evicted.

It's possible to check cache contents from the context of your controlled pages via [`window.caches`](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/window-caches/index.html), but that only works when users have one of your web pages open, and you need to explicitly poll to check cache contents, as there are no events to listen to for cache updates.